# Elasticsearch - Mapping fields from other indices

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I define mapping in Elasticsearch 7 to index a document with a field value from another index? For example,  if I have a `users` index which has a mapping for `name`, `email` and `account_number` but the `account_number` value is actually in another index called `accounts` in field `number`.

I've tried something like this without much success (I only see "name", "email" and "account_id" in the results):

```
PUT users/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "account_id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "accounts": {
      "properties": { 
        "number":  {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `accounts` index has the following mapping:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "number": {
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the mapping for the fields or the actual value of the field? The mappings are per index, you can't import mappings, the closest to it would be using index templates that applies the same mapping to multiple index patterns, from version 7.8+ you also have component templates. You also can't index a field in indexA with a value from indexB without querying the indexB before, using logstash or some custom script.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, I think that's what I'm trying to accomplish. A user has an account_id field and I want a user document to contain the account number from the accounts index based on the account_id. That's not possible unless it's created manually, correct?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to implement field joining as is usually done in relational databases. In elasticsearch, this is possible only if the documents are in the same index. ([Link to doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/parent-join.html)). But it seems to me that in your case you need to work differently, I think your Account object needs to be [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) for User.

```
PUT /users/_mapping
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "account": {
        "type": "nested"
       }
     }
   } 
}
```

You can further search as if it were a separate document.

```
GET /users/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "account",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "account.number": 1 } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```